# gStreamer queue element blocks data when used conjunction with valve

Tags: queue, multimedia, gstreamer

I have the following pipeline:

```
gst_element_link_many (videosrc, q1, rlvideoqueue, rlvvalve, q3, videoparse, videoqueue, mux, filesink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many (audiosrc, q2, rlaudioqueue, rlavalve, q4, audioparse, audioqueue, mux, NULL);
```

where `rlvideoqueue`, `rlaudioqueue` is a queue element and `rlvvalve`, `rlavalve` is a valve,

Initially the valve's drop value is set to `TRUE` and `rlvideoqueue`, `rlaudioqueue` is set to hold buffers for 15 seconds (`min-threshold-time=15000000000 min-threshold-buffers=0 min-threshold-bytes=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=15000000000`).

As soon as there is a event the valve's drop value is set to `FALSE`. But it never writes to the filesink, I have also set the async to `FALSE` but no luck, the data is just accumulated in the queue.

What is the reason for data being held up in queue.

If and only if `min-threshold-time` is set to 0 then only it passes data to next element and data is written to file.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Stop-start-recording-using-Valve-element-td4661728.html

you have to add async=false to your filesink